# .NET CSC Compiler Temp Path

Tags: .net, environment-variables, temp, csc

For some of my project works, i am using Microsoft `CSC` Compiler to generate `DLLs` in run time. The code files, references are dynamically parsed as arguments and i am invoking  `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe` as a process.

The whole thing worked fine in my environment, but for some reasons while i am using the same setup in my server. I am facing some problems. `CSC` compiler by default uses **TEMP** folder for generating `DLLs` files then copy the actual output `DLLs` to the defined output location.

I want to make `CSC` compiler to use a different  **TEMP** folder (i.e. `X:\MyOwnTemp\`), rather than using common TEMP folder (common temp i.e. Specific for users / Environmental variable) . Where other applications still use common temp.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx